Laravel Session isn't working properly – VerifyCsrfToken
I've been handed a Laravel project (10.x) that uses Session for its authentication, and for some reason I cannot figure out why it's not working normally. When I log-in and click "remember me" the authentication pushes through, but without it I get redirected to the login page.
I have verified that I have csrf token in the form as well as in the header.
I have verified that this is sent along with my credentials.
I have tried switching the session driver to file, database, and redis.
I have tried adding a '*' in the $exclude, but also not working
It looks like the problem resides inn the VerifyCsrfToken middleware. I tried logging everything that goes there and the _token sent and the value from $request->session()->token() are different, and the hash_equals() also returns false. But I cannot figure out what is happening here.

Are you using custom code for VerifyCsrfToken middleware and/or authentication, and if so what does it do? Also I thought the CSRF token and session token are different things but I am unsure. Are you allowed to show us some code about the handling of this remember-me function?

So, can you clarify, the problem is: logging in WITHOUT ticking 'remember me' seems to fail, and you are taken back to log in page immediately?

I'd suggest trying to: look at the network tab and follow the sequence of requests, in case you spot anything helpful. Do you get logged in (success), redirected (to intended page), and then immediately redirected again to the log in page?
I'd then check how long the session is supposed to live (in config/session.php) for and see if that works properly.
Maybe also check login method hasn't been modified from default, and is the order / config of middlewares changed at all?

@JorisJ1 I don't, just the default VerifyCsrf middleware. I figured out it was the problem because I tried disabling it. And if I disable it in the Kernel, the login pushes through IF I click on "remember"

@benjaminhull that is correct, that's how it goes exactly. But that only happens if I disable the VerifyCsrf middleware. If I put it back, it just gives me 419.

@benjaminhull I tried that. And from my observation, the CSRF token somehow gets regenerated during the request, so the csrf token from the form isn't valid anymore. I have tried creating GET route that logs in a certain user, then tries to get the logged in user via Auth::user(), the user can be fetched through this method (those two steps happens in the same request). But if I separate them (1 request logs in that user, 1 request shows the logged in user), the Auth::user just returns null

"that only happens if I disable the VerifyCsrf middleware. If I put it back, it just gives me 419" - sounds like the project has two problems then. One is the VerifyCsrf not working correctly; the other is the session seems to time out immediately. Try to isolate and solve one at a time would be best.
